# Angular automatically save form when valid

Tags: angularjs

I have several forms which created by ng-repeat.
Each form has multiple fields, not all forms necessarily has the same fields.
I want to save form in dataBase when all fields are valid, automatically.

```
<div ng-repeat="a in arr">
 <form name="myForm">
    phone{{a}}:<input type="phone" name="phone" ng-model="a.phone" ng-pattern="[0-9]" />
    text{{a}}:<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="a.name" require/>
  </form>
</div>
```

I dont have any submit button, or another indication when finish to fill all fields, just if the form is valid I want to save.

How can I know if user finish to type all fields? I perfer to not use watch

Comment: What do you mean with "not all forms necessarily has the same fields". How do you do this with an angular repeat?

Comment: there are fields which I show just if a==1, etc